# Getting unexepted Reference Error while generating CSR in Gatsby [ReactJS]

Tags: reactjs, csr, gatsby

I am trying to generate CSR in gatsby (ReactJS), I am following this [csrhelp](https://github.com/PeculiarVentures/csrhelp) package which is built in AngularJs, I am just trying to use the same in ReactJs, but when I try to run the following code it returns unexpected error.

```
let pkcs10_simpl = new org.pkijs.simpl.PKCS10();
```

the error is:

> ReferenceError: org is not defined

[image]

Even I have also imported the [pkijs](https://www.npmjs.com/package/pkijs) package for this.

Please help me to sort out this issue.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

CSRHelp was written with v1 of PKIjs which has been deprecated. I suspect your using PKIjsv2. Look at the this example https://github.com/PeculiarVentures/PKI.js/tree/master/examples/PKCS10ComplexExample